# What is and how to work with the Async method auto generated by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, asynchronous

I have my WCF service, when I try to call my method from the client side there are two of them, my method `Foo()` and another method `FooAsync()` that the VS is creating.

- With this done, do I need to program my system to be Async?
- Is WCF easing my work and making the same method able to be called
  asynchronous?
- Do I need to invoke it in a Task<> or is enough whit calling it
  like my original method? `client.FooAsync();`
- Which is the right way to implement it?

Comment: You can find the answers for you questions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f10cee3-9747-4cc7-8431-353304abf9d1/wcf-not-generating-async-methods?forum=csharpgeneral  and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms730059(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, it seems useful.